# How to create animated "wave" effect in vuejs?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, svg

what is the name of this effect? Above the heading **What is a sofbox?** I mean the wave line, like
[here](http://iqonic.design/sofbox-vue/landing-page-1).

It is also above the title **Readymade Multi-use Landing Homepages** [here](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/aeroland-app-sass-landing-page-template/full_screen_preview/25198880?_ga=2.202473492.428106023.1591053218-626376510.1588510113&irgwc=1&clickid=WN5RaQyy9xyORJPwUx0Mo3EWUki3unXlF1PnzY0&iradid=275988&irpid=2305834&iradtype=ONLINE_TRACKING_LINK&irmptype=mediapartner&mp_value1=&utm_campaign=af_impact_radius_2305834&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=impact_radius). I don't know what it's called, I can't find it.

How can I make this animated effect (from the second link) and responsive as it is on that page? Can anyone help? The ideal solution would be vuejs, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not necessarily need `Vue.js` or even `js` to achieve that. You can do it with just `CSS`.

In the first example, it seems to be simply an image (white wave) positioned `:after` the `div` with the background picture. It is on the top of the actual div, you can use `z-index` for that.

The second example is a bit funkier. It is `SVG` (white wave) that is animated to move to the left. So it could really be the same picture as from the first example but you would just add animation to move the element to the left infinitely.

Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/frmtgnu9/1/). I created pretty much the same effect with `SVG`.

Also, have a look [here](https://getwaves.io/) - you can customise your own wave easily.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh yes, that generator combined with keyframes is what I wanted, thanks a lot

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help. Good luck.